# Url Not Working in My Webservice

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

I am calling webservice which takes two parameters like category and salt then provide the json output with constructed url but url is not working. PFA url

Service Url:
http://qalisting.corelogic.com/ChaseListingServices/v1.5/test

constructed URL: http://qalisting.corelogic.com/ChaseListingServices/v1.5/listings/search/test/0/4e9c00b32794edfeba257aa0c74f500b

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message on your constructed URL, the Service needs to be called using a `POST` and not a `GET` Request.

Responding to your comments: it's not the URL which is the problem but how it is called. When you follow a link, such as the one you posted - the browser sends it as a GET request. The service is expecting the JSON arguments as part of the "body" of a POST request. This must be done programmatically.

Comment: can u give me any sample url